# Bug in the logo appearance with the new black top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, logo

With the new fancy black top bar, the logo of the site got mutilated. I believe that the following CSS fix would bring it close to the original state, however, I'm not 100% sure and IMHO the old version should be checked.

[image: The red and blue marks should be aligned.]

```
.new-topbar .container #header #hlogo {
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.new-topbar .container #header #hlogo a {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Spotted on **Firefox 25.0, Fedora 13, GNOME 2.30.2, kernel 2.6.34.9**

EDIT: If you wish to use the above fix through Stylish, you ought to put `!important` everywhere:

```
.new-topbar .container #header #hlogo {
    margin-top: 13px !important;
    margin-bottom: 7px !important;
}

.new-topbar .container #header #hlogo a {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "mutilated"? On my computer, using FF 25.0.1 and Chromium 30.0.1599.114, the logo is shown as before the introduction of the bar.

Comment: @Jake screenshot and specs added.

Comment: Aah, yes, now that I see it it's hard to miss! Thanks for the edit!

Comment: I'm not seeing this problem in Safari or Firefox on a Mac. Is this a platform dependent problem or was this fixed? If it was fixed it would be a good idea to finalise this thread.

Comment: @GeoffPointer No, it was not fixed, at least not for me. Can you please post a screenshot?

Comment: @GeoffPointer It's not the red and blue things that I see, these serve only as helper lines. The problem is that they should be vertical aligned: The horizontal line is the axis of the `{TeX}` logo.

Comment: Okay, I see it now, sorry. Although it obviously didn't look mutilated to me until you pointed it out. Has someone got a pic of what it used to look like? Have you reported it, or is it going to go the way of everything else?

Comment: @GeoffPointer This is _the_ official way to report bugs, by a [meta-tag:bug] meta post. I couldn't find a screen-shot of the original site design.

Comment: Here you go: [Pre Update TeX.SE Appearance](http://geoffpointer.com/PatchUp/old_tex_se.png).

Comment: While dealing with [How can I make the top header fixed in my browser?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4339) I noticed that the following code, also specific for (meta).tex.sx, should be added (here in my comment as one-liner): `.container {background-position: 5px 25px !important;}`. The original vertical shift is -9px, the topbar height is 34px, hence the 25px.

Answer (score 4):

Gotta love multiple site designs. :)

This will be fixed in the next build. Keep an eye out for revision 2014.5.19.1614, although I bet you'll notice the change in the logo at the top way before the tiny revision number at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: The number at the bottom is `rev 2014.5.19.1614` but the logo is still in the wrong place …

Comment: It's fixed in the sense of the hrule alignment. However, it's still far from [the original]: the logo used to have higher height to show more of the typeset equations and other stuff on background.

Comment: @Tobi My bad. I should've said 1615.

Comment: @tohecz I missed that entirely, sorry 'bout that. Will be fixed in the next build (\*double-checks the number\*) ... rev 2014.5.20.1617.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Trivia: at each bugfix release of TeX, the version number acquires one more digit, so that it tends to the limit π. `:)`

Comment: Thanks @Anna. The logo used to be more spaced, but I think we'll get used to it.

Comment: Sorry for the unrelated comment, but could you take a look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3824/can-the-box-made-by-the-kbd-html-tag-be-made-smaller?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'll take a look. For some reason, there's been historical resistance to changing that (across a number of sites), so I'm gonna have to check with the design team.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks.