# How can I make the top header fixed in my browser?

Tags: discussion

I have often thought that it might be useful to have the top bar (with its inbox and review notifications) fixed to the top of the page.  This lets you always have a view of your status and items that are coming in, even while reading through lengthy questions/answers.

What is the most efficient way to do this, reaching as many browsers as possible?

Answer (score 8):

This quick TamperMonkey script can be installed in much the same way as the "select code" block from this question: [How to make `select code` work with google chrome?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/how-to-make-select-code-work-with-google-chrome)

[TamperMonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) is compatible with "Google Chrome, Opera, Chromium and a lot of their derivates like CoolNovo and Rockmelt."

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Makes the top bar "fixed"
// @namespace      http://www.example.com/
// @description    Makes the top bar "fixed"
// @include        http://tex.stackexchange.com/*
// @include        https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;

$("div.topbar").css('position','fixed');   // Fix the topbar
$("div.topbar").css('z-index','5');        // Move it to the top
$("div#header").css('padding-top','25px'); // Pad the rest of the page
```

### To Install...

#### For Chrome

1. Install the Tampermonkey Web Extension for Chrome: [Link to Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)
2. This should enable a new button that appears by your URL bar.  Use the "Add a new script..." button to, well, add a new script.

   [image: addnewscript]
3. Copy and paste the code from above into the window that appears.

   [image: pastecode]
4. Be sure to use the "Save" button [image: save] (**not** "Save to Disk" [image: savetodisk]) to save and enable the script.
5. Enjoy!  The script is enabled by default only on TeX.SE and Meta.TeX.SE, but it would probably be usable on other 2.0 SE sites with appropriate alterations to the `@include` lines.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly has to be done with this code? I don't find where to paste it...

Comment: @Dror I added install instructions for Chrome ... let me know if these don't match your experience.

Comment: It simply didn't cross my mind to click the new icon... Thanks! Thats brilliant!

Comment: Will this work with Firefox?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I haven't tested it with Firefox, but it should be compatible "out of the box" with the [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) AddOn for Firefox.  TamperMonkey was built with the same syntax as GreaseMonkey.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

While the [Tampermonkey code of cslstr](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4340/) should work in Firefox/Seamonkey with [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) or [Scriptish](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/scriptish/) (I didn’t test) it is not necessary, as it effectively executes CSS code. So I rewrote it, see below.

Copy the following code into your `userContent.css` (cf. [Customizing Mozilla](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html)) or into [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/stylish/). In first case you will have to restart your browser, in second case it works immediately after saving.

```
@-moz-document domain(stackexchange.com),
               domain(stackoverflow.com) {
.topbar {
  position: fixed !important;
  z-index: 101 !important;
}
#header {
  padding-top: 34px !important;
}}
```

Some remarks:

- In this way it works for all `stackexchange.com` sites and `stackoverflow.com` including the meta subsites. It could be easily enhanced for other StackExchange domains by adding them separated with commas.
- It turned out that `z-index: 2` would be enough for `⟨meta.⟩tex.se`, but not for the tour-page `⟨meta.⟩tex.stackexchange.com/tour`. You need a value of 101 (make a test with 100 …), and if there were changes in future it could be more increased, of course.
- A look into the original code revealed that the topbar has been defined to have a height of 34px, not 25px as in clstr’s code.

---

For an additional change – or better: fix – specifically for `domain(tex.stackexchange.com)` see [Bug in the logo appearance with the new black top bar](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/) and my comment below this ([Bug in the logo appearance with the new black top bar](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/#comment14317_4007)).

Answer (score 4):

See [Gallery of custom styles and/or scripts for the top-bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210041/gallery-of-custom-styles-and-or-scripts-for-the-top-bar); I use the [StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ Fixes](http://userstyles.org/styles/95794/stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-fixes) together with [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/stylish/) for Firefox.